# shift link to the right using html or css?

Tags: html, css

How can I shift the `LINK 1` a bit to the right?

```
<div id="Links_1">
  <a class="link_1" href="#">LINK 1 </a> 
  <a class="link_2" href="#">LINK 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how the resulting page is displayed now and how it should be displayed?

Comment: http://cdn.imgsnap.com/images/2015/11/04/upoad.png
thats how my page looks like
m trying to shift the Home link to the right just on top of the verticle line

Comment: Also post the CSS which you are currently using. Demo is better.

Comment: i have tried a bunch of CSS for that but doesn't work so i think i can say that i don't have any CSS for that particular div

Comment: Try placing margins on your links

Answer (score 1):

```
a.link_1 {
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left: 14px;
}
```

i was able to fix it with this codes thanks for the help